# Error EntityType has no key defined. Even after adding Key Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce

I'm getting an error:

> EntityType 'Person' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

even after adding `[Key]` annotation.

I already installed packages for `EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact` version 6.1.3

Is this error is something to do with SQL Server Compact Edition or am I missing some other configuration?

Below is my class definition for `Person`

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id;

    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the appropriate Email Address")]
    public string Email;

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your full name")]
    public string FullName;

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your company name")]
    public string CompanyName;

    public string Password;

    public bool IsAdmin = false;
}
```

Context definition:

```
public class WorkLogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Connection string in `web.config`:

```
<add name="WorkLogContext"          
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|WorkLog.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding getters and setters to your Person entity properties? public int Id { get; set; } public string Email {get; set;} etc..

Comment: When I change the properties to use get and set accessors then it work.

Comment: thanks @JDupont I did that and it work, can you explain why such restriction?

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics off of the top of my head. I would assume that EntityFramework uses the getter and setter methods when defining its maps.